# Using jQuery to post multiple values to server

Tags: php, jquery

The following script will send `$_POST['id']=[1,2,3]` to the server.

Instead I wish to either send `$_POST['id']=[[1,'extra1'],[2,'extra2'],[3,'extra3']]` to the server, or send both `$_POST['id']=[1,2,3]` and `$_POST['extra']=['extra1','extra2','extra3']` to the server.

I could do so by iterating over the table, but the HTML is PHP generated, and instead I would like to modify the HTML to make doing so as straightforward as possible.

How is this best accomplished?

https://jsfiddle.net/5a8cLt08/2/

```
$('#go').click(function() {
  var data = $('#mytable tbody input.cb:checked').serializeArray();
  console.log('data', data);
  $.post('ajax.php', data, function(json) {
    console.log('json', json);
  }, 'json');
});

<table id='mytable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="1" secondValue="extra1" name="id[]">
      </td>
      <td>bla1</td>
      <td>
        <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="2" secondValue="extra2" name="id[]">
      </td>
      <td>bla2</td>
      <td>
        <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="3" secondValue="extra3" name="id[]">
      </td>
      <td>bla3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="go">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="1" name="id[]">
<input type="hidden" name="extras[1]" value="extra1" />
```

This will populate the $_POST['extras'] with an associative array of id => extra.
This is of course assuming you're populating this via a PHP loop and can achieve the above easily.

If not you'll probably need to use JavaScript to extract the attributes you want from the inputs.

**Update**

You can also pass JSON values to this. Ideally you'd want to do a `$valueData = json_encode` to the data you want to pass as a value.

The input will look something like :

```
    <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value='{ "id": 1, "extras": "extra1"  }' name="id[]">
```

Your $_POST will be something like:

```
$_POST["id"] = [ 
    '{ id: 1, extras: "extra1" }', ... 
]
```

You can get the required data by doing something like:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["id"][0]);

$id = $data->id; $extra = $data->extras;
```

Comment: Yes, I suppose I could do so, and it would be easy to do so.  It would, however, result in extra data being posted which isn't needed as only the extra values associated with checked values are needed.  I was wondering if I could use something like `value=[1,'extra1']`, but don't expect I can.  Or maybe putting a `data` value in each input, selecting the matched `input.cb:checked`, and some how serializing the `data` values?

Comment: @user1032531 You can set a JSON encoded value in your value and then decode it using `json_decode` probably and not use the hidden field at all.

Comment: @would a typical `value` look like I showed it in my previous comment, or would it have quotes around it to be valid HTML?

Comment: Nice!  I will select it as an answer after I test it.  Thanks!

Comment: For this to work, you need to put quotes around the JSON property names in the HTML.

Comment: @user1032531 Yes, you're right. Completely forgot about that. I was writing them as though they were JavaScript variables which they aren't.